# how to append a variable to every request in nginx?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a situation where I need to append a country code to all the request in nginx.

For example, if a user access http://example.com:3333/html/about, then I should redirect (using rewrite in nginx) to http://example.com:3333/html/about?country_code=en

I have the following rewrite, but I get 'too many loops'.

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ http://$host:3333/$1?country_code=en last;
```

How do I fix it?

nginx.conf

```
server {
    ### USA specific config ###                                                                                                                                                                     
    if ($geoip_country_code = US) {
        # do something here for USA visitors;
        # root path /var/www/html/content/usa/;                                                                                                                                                     
        rewrite ^(.*)$ http://$host:3333/$1?country_code=en last;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if ($geoip_country_code = US) {
    set $test "US";
}
if ($arg_country_code != 'en') {
    set $test "{$test}_R";
}
if ($test = 'US_R') {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://$host:3333/$1?country_code=en last;
}
```

Comment: @Timofey Stolbov // I'm sorry, I forgot to put last on my post. I actually have last in my original code.

Comment: @Timofey Stolbov // beautiful!!! it works!! um..one last question.. is it possible to hide ?country_code=en to users? i want to use clear url eventually

Comment: @Moon If this server listens on 3333 port you can try `rewrite ^(.*) $1?country_code=en last;` But I see too little of nginx.conf to be assured.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

original:

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ http://$host:3333/$1?country_code=en
```

new:

```
rewrite ^(.*)(?!\?country_code=[a-z][a-z])$ http://$host:3333/$1?country_code=en
```

I assume that nginx supports negative lookahead assertions using the common `(?!...)` syntax. The negative lookahead says that the match (and rewriting) should happen when the `?country_code=nn` *isn't* at the end of the url. (If it is in the middle of the URL, this rewrite will still happen.)

Comment: // thank you for the reply. Can I do it without checking if a request already contains country or not? if I do what you suggested, users can send country_code manually to override country_code.